# Use key or ref in React-Native

Tags: loops, key, react-native

So, I am having issue with using loop in react-native, mostly related to how to update the default value ad get each value of text input if I am looping many text inputs. I am thinking the solution is to use the key, but I am not sure how to implement it to the code. Or maybe can we use ref?

So the details of the problem is like this: The noGuest in the loop is input by user, with the maximum of number of 4 guest. Based on the drop-down value inside each loop, I want to directly update all of the field in that current index with existing data, by setting the state. But because I don't know how to use the key, when I select an option in the drop-down of Guest 1, ALL fields (including Guest 2, Guest 3, Guest 4) are actually updated with the existing data. Getting the value of each text-input maybe pretty straightforward if I manage to solve the previous issue.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        guestInfo: '',
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
    };  
}
onGuestNameChange(guestName) {
    console.log('executing onGuestNameChange');
    let guest = guestName.value;
    var len = guest_profile.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        let row = guest_profile[i];
        console.log(row.first_name);
        if(row.first_name == guest) {
            this.setState({
                first_name : row.first_name,
                last_name : row.last_name,
            });
        }
    }
    var guestInfo = this.generateguestInfoField();
    this.setState({guestInfo : guestInfo});
}
generateguestInfoField() {
    var noGuest = this.state.guest;
    var guestInfo = [];
    for(let i = 1; i < noGuest; i++){
        guestInfo.push(
            <View style={styles.guestFormField} key = {i}>
                <View style={styles.guestTitle}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 16, color:'black'}}>Guest {i}</Text>
                    <Dropdown style={{ height: 20, width: 150}}
                    values={guest_name} selected={0} 
                    onChange={this.onGuestNameChange.bind(this)} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.guestInput}>
                    <Text style={styles.guestLabel}>First Name</Text>
                    <View style={styles.guestFieldBox}>
                        <TextInput 
                            style={styles.guestField}
                            underlineColorAndroid={'white'}
                            defaultValue={this.state.first_name}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.guestInput}>
                    <Text style={styles.guestLabel}>Last Name</Text>
                    <View style={styles.guestFieldBox}>
                        <TextInput 
                            style={styles.guestField}
                            underlineColorAndroid={'white'}
                            defaultValue={this.state.last_name}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
    return guestInfo;
}
```

Any suggestion is abundantly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some more code, namely onGuestNameChange. thanks!

Comment: Hi Nader, I added the code already. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have all of the code for your component, but from what I can tell, something like this should solve your problem:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        guestInfo: '',
        guests: []
    };  
}
onGuestNameChange(guestName, i) {
    console.log('executing onGuestNameChange');
    let guest = guestName.value;
    let guests = []
    var len = guest_profile.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        let row = guest_profile[i];
        console.log(row.first_name);
        if(row.first_name == guest) {
            guests.push(row)
        }
    }
    this.setState({
      guestInfo : guestInfo,
      guests: guests
    })
    var guestInfo = this.generateguestInfoField();

}

generateguestInfoField() {
    var noGuest = this.state.guest;
    var guestInfo = [];
    for(let i = 1; i < noGuest; i++){
        guestInfo.push(
            <View style={styles.guestFormField} key = {i}>
                <View style={styles.guestTitle}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 16, color:'black'}}>Guest {i}</Text>
                    <Dropdown style={{ height: 20, width: 150}}
                    values={guest_name} selected={0} 
                    onChange={this.onGuestNameChange.bind(this, i)} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.guestInput}>
                    <Text style={styles.guestLabel}>First Name</Text>
                    <View style={styles.guestFieldBox}>
                        <TextInput 
                            style={styles.guestField}
                            underlineColorAndroid={'white'}
                            defaultValue={this.state.guests[i].first_name}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.guestInput}>
                    <Text style={styles.guestLabel}>Last Name</Text>
                    <View style={styles.guestFieldBox}>
                        <TextInput 
                            style={styles.guestField}
                            underlineColorAndroid={'white'}
                            defaultValue={this.state.guests[i].last_name}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
    return guestInfo;
}
```

Comment: I got an error regarding the defaultValue, in which it says that `this.state.guests[i].first_name` is undefined (cannot get property first_name of undefined). I already add `guests: []` in constructor. but it is still not working.